# session variable / temp data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, session-variables

So on the users page the user can use a drop down to select their name and then click 'view' to view the list of holidays they have previously booked.  From here they can choose 'select new' which will allow the user to create a new holiday.  This all works fine however I want the username to be stored from the original drop down and displayed in the creating page.  Instead of having 2 seperate drop downs on each page.

I have tried:

My first drop down in my Index.chtml

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HList4DD.First().HolidayDate, new SelectList(Model.PList4DD, "Id", "Name", Model.currentPersonID), "--select--")
```

My second drop Down on the create view:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PersonId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Id, "Value", "Text"),"---Select---")
```

---

I wanted to change this to the name of the user previously selected so in my get of the Index I have used:

```
TempData["CurrentPersonID"] =currentPersonID;
```

Then to replace my second drop down im trying something like:

```
@TempData["CurrentPersonID"]

<div>
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.currentPersonID, "currentPersonID")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonId) 
</div>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You seem to not really be asking a specific question.  What works and what doesn't?  What about your solution do you not like?  Are you curious if you are using TempData incorrectly? (fyi you seem to be since TempData is meant to be very short lived)

Comment: `TempData` only lasts for one redirect. You may want to try using `ViewData` instead. But as Bryan said, your question is too vague to give an appropriate response.